# Detecting changes within a dataset in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has time-ordered values:

```
id
date
value
```

`value` is often the same for hundreds of records at a strech, and I'd like to be able to determine when `value` changes. In other words, I would like to know when d/dx (the derivative of the data) does not equal 0!

It seems like there should be a fairly common pattern but I can't find any examples or come up with one myself. I did find [an example](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#798) where this change detection was done, but I can't use it because my database adapter pools connections and queries are not necessarily issued on the same connection. Similarly, I'd rather not use a database trigger.

Here's an example table:

```
id | date             | value
1  | 2011-04-05 12:00 | 33
2  | 2011-04-06 12:00 | 39
3  | 2011-04-07 12:00 | 39
...
72 | 2011-05-16 12:00 | 39
73 | 2011-05-17 12:00 | 37
74 | 2011-05-18 12:00 | 33
75 | 2011-05-19 12:00 | 33
...
```

I'm looking for a query that could pull back the rows where the values change:

```
id | date             | value
1  | 2011-04-05 12:00 | 33
2  | 2011-04-06 12:00 | 39
73 | 2011-05-17 12:00 | 37
74 | 2011-05-18 12:00 | 33
```

Its not necessary that the first row to be included in the result, since a table with identical values would return zero rows (i.e. there are no changes).

Comment: Do you mean you want to see where it changes as you iterate through it?  What language are you reading it from?  Or do you want it in plain sql language?

Comment: The data is quite large so I wouldn't want to iterate through each entry. Instead, I'd ultimately like a listing of rows that correspond to the changes. I'll update the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Is there anything distinct about the values that we could use to separate one from another?

Comment: They're just data points. The only real distinct information is that they are time-ordered and may or may not be at constant offsets from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id, t.date, t.value, if( (

SELECT td.value AS last_value
FROM tab td
WHERE td.date < t.date
ORDER BY td.date DESC
LIMIT 1
) <> t.value, 'changed', 'unchanged' ) AS cstatus
FROM tab t order by date
```

Not a very efficient query, slow on large sets, but does the trick.
Adding a counter lets say num_repeated as another column, updated on insert would be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It is indeed slow... 3 seconds for only 2500 records. I'll have to take your suggestion to add another column to mark changes. Do you think a inner join version would perform any better?

Comment: Maybe, however I can't find any easy query to do the same job with a join. But 3 seconds for a such set is very long, do you have any index covering date column? You could also try using id instead of dates, but that would work only if higher id meant higher (more recent) date for all records.

Comment: The table I'm testing against has over 1 million rows, but this FK only has ~2500 records. I do have an index on the date column, and EXPLAIN output shows that it is being used (for the subquery, anyway). Some queries I found did an entire table scan of all 1 million rows even though I specified the FK condition! The `id` option utilizing id +/- 1 would be useful if I could guarantee insert order (which I can't). I suppose utilizing a sequence number with an index would provide comparable efficiency.

Comment: By the way, I did add a sequence number based on the time of the date record. This gives me a +/- relationship and makes it much easier to implement this feature (as well as some others).

Answer (score 1):

uh, use a `group by`?

```
select min(id), min(date), value
from ...
group by value
order by id asc
```

Comment: `group_by` is a naive approach... it won't, for example, let you detect changing from value X to value Y and back to value X.